# Data is not displayed after Page Redirect ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am caught up in a strange scenario with developing a simple Login functionality in ASP.NET. There are two pages, the `LoginPage.aspx` and `Default.aspx` . After user provides valid credentials on Login Page, he/she is redirected to Default page. I want to display user login information on top of Default page, for that purpose I have added following HTML:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div id="demo_header" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="loggedinUsername" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="logout" runat="server" Text="Logout!" ForeColor="Black" OnClick="Logout"></asp:LinkButton>
    ...
</div>
</form>
```

And in Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Session["LoggedinUser"] != null)
        {
            loggedinUsername.Text = "Welcome " + Session["LoggedinUser"].ToString() + " ";
            logout.Visible = true;
            demo_header.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            logout.Visible = false;
            demo_header.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

Here is the code which executes when user presses Login button on LoginPage.aspx:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LoginEmail.ToString() == string.Empty || LoginPassword.ToString() == string.Empty)
    {
        Session["RedirectReaasonFlag"] = "Credentials null";
        login_error_msg.Text = "Please Provide Email/Password!";
    }
    else 
    {
        UserStandard User = new UserStandard();
        User._Email = LoginEmail.Text;
        User._password = LoginPassword.Text;
        Dictionary<int, string> LoggedinUserData = User.AuthenticateUser(User);
        if (LoggedinUserData.Count == 1)
        {
            Session["LoggedinUserID"] = LoggedinUserData.ElementAt(0).Key;
            Session["LoggedinUser"] = LoggedinUserData.ElementAt(0).Value;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
            Session["RedirectReaasonFlag"]= "Invalid Login Attempt";
    }
}
```

But somehow when user is redirected on Default page, its name and Log out hyperlink is not shown. This is very simple task and this situation is eating up my brain. Please help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the login code placed? on default.aspx? or on loginPage.aspx?
the session is set only after you refresh the page

Comment: set `demo_header.Visible = true;` in `if` block

Comment: Login code is on LoginPage.aspx . I have debugged the code and IF statements of Default page do execute but data is not displayed in browser...

Comment: See my edit. Code added of LoginPage.aspx.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `loggedinUsername` label and your `logout` link button are inside a `div` which you are setting `Visible = false`.  So, you are telling the browser to hide these elements when the login is successful.  Try setting `demo_header.Visible = true` instead.

Comment: Can't believe what a stupid mistake I was making!! thanks a lot.

Comment: It happens to us all at one time or another.  Sometimes all you need are a fresh set of eyes on the problem.